# Spring MVC 3.0 parsing item class in JSON

Tags: java, json, jquery, spring-mvc

I have class named Person and it looks like this.

```
public class Person{
public Person(){}

private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Supervisor supervisor;

//setters and getters
}

public class Supervisor{
public Supervisor(){}
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

//setters and getters
}
```

Now I've HTML form which has inputs for person and supervisor items (firstname, lastname, etc...)
On the server side I have Spring MVC controller and I'm doing the following:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/getperson.do",method = RequestMethod.POST)
         @ResponseBody
          public String getPersonByAjax(@RequestBody Person person){ 

          }
```

Will my superuser be parsed as item inside Person class?

How my JSON string should look like?

Can I achieve it using JQuery or I should create my JSON string manually?

Comment: You have a typo in your code SuperVisor should be Supervisor for starters

Comment: Sure, I jut typed this code in text form. thanks.

Comment: As an aside, your "Will my superuser be parsed as person item?" should be "Will my supervisor be parsed as person item?"

Comment: @Bozho, Not yet, because I just wonder how ny JSON should look like.

Comment: @karianna - Sorry. I just described it wrong. I can blame it on a noise beside my cubic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON message should look like the following:

```
{
    "id": ...,
    "firstName": ...,
    "lastName": ...,
    "supervisor": {
        "id": ...,
        "firstName": ...,
        "lastName": ...    
    }
}
```

jQuery can't automatically serialize a form into this representation, so you need some manual processing.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want you Supervisor to extend Person?

Or even change Person into an interface and have Supervisor implement that interface and add a new Employee class to represent a Person that has a Supervisor.

I'd resolve that structure in order to have your getPersonByAjax to accept all types of Persons.

Then you can start worrying about your JSON.

Comment: No I reather prefer not to do it. Person and Supervisor are completely different entities. I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: In that case no you won't be able to parse Supervisor as a Person.  They're completely unrelated in your model of the world.